# How can I know when the file download/"Save As" prompt appears?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link on a page

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="DownloadCsv">Download CSV</a>
```

When the user clicks on said link, the server responds with the header `Content-Disposition: attachment` to prompt the user with the "Save File" Dialog.

What I'd like to accomplish is: disable the link while the server is generating its response, and enable it once the server responds.

Is there any event fired for that response from the server? Or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through my old questions. I even don't remember what I need it for but I decided to answer on this now because it has not been solved yet after 3.5 years... It can be accomplished this way

Link can be

```
<a class="btn btn-success" onclick="clickHandler(this); return false;">Download CSV</a>
```

Handler

```
    function clickHandler(element) {
        //disable link
        var href = element.href;
        element.href = 'javascript:void(0)';

        //download file
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'DownloadCsv', true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
          if (this.status == 200) {
            var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
            var i = uInt8Array.length;
            var binaryString = new Array(i);
            while (i--) { binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]); }
            var data = binaryString.join('');

            //initiate save as dialog
            var base64 = window.btoa(data);
            var a = document.createElement('a'); 
            a.href = 'data:application/csv;base64,'+ base64; 
            a.setAttribute('download', 'data.csv');
            a.click();

            //enable link
            element.href = href;
          }
        };

        xhr.send(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that comes to my mind is using AJAX.
You first download it with AJAX where you have events that guide you (like ready state etc.).
Then you do the actual download, but at that point it is served from the browsers cache.
So it is not actually downloaded but instantly loaded from disk.
The user will not tell the difference but you will be able to detect the end of the actual download.

Comment: Problem is it is not loaded from cache. May be it's related with headers of requests need to check it. Thank you for answer.